# Infinite series contradiction

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the value of $$1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\cdots$$

I added and subtracted $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots$ to get $$\big(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\cdots\big) - 2\big(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots\big)$$
The value of the above series is zero!

But if I take the taylor expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ and substitute $x=1$, I get the sum of series as $\ln 2$.

I got this when I was solving a problem in physics where I was asked to find the potential at $(0,0)$, if $+q$ charges are placed at $x=x_0$, $x=3x_0$, .... and $-q$ was placed at $x=2x_0$, $x=4x_0$, ....

Comment: [Terms rearrangement in series conditionally converging never should do you, young padawan.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem)

Comment: Is this a bad question? I have never come across such situations. All I had in mind was to add the missing positive terms.

Comment: No, it's a perfectly fine question to ask, but it is a bad thing to do. The reason is given in the link I've provided: if you rearrange the summands of not absolutely converging series, the sum changes. This does not happen to absolutely converging series.

Comment: What do you mean by "absolutely converging"? What's the difference?

Comment: Do you mean series like decreasing GP?

Comment: Have you followed the link I've provided? All the definitions are there.

Comment: A series $\sum a_k$ is absolutely convergent if $\sum |a_k|$ is convergent, which is not the case here since the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: It's still not clear to me. What's the mistake in my approach? Can you explain it in simple words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have positive terms that go to ∞ and negative terms that go to -∞, then you can claim **any** number as the sum of the combined ∞-∞ by re-arranging the specific numbers

Take some number N. Add positive terms until you get higher than N, then negative terms until you are lower than N, then more positive terms until you are higher again, then more negative terms until you are lower again...